# SharedPreferences on android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I have a problem with `SharedPreferences` and my `PreferenceActivity`. I need that my application can difference between differentes preferences and users, so every user has his own preferences. I thought in use `SharedPreferences` sending to it the user ID to get the correct options. The problem is that I dont know how to do for my PreferenceActivity use that specific options. Currently, It is using the context options, so when I restart my application, it loads the last options modifieds...

How can I configure my preferenceActivities to store his changes in the `sharedpreferences` that I want? And for the load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's unusual to support the concept of 'users' on Android - most apps assume a phone has a single user.

That said, you can create custom SharedPreferences like this

```
SharedPreferences userprefs = getSharedPreferences(username,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

For your PreferenceActivity, in onCreate you do this

```
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(username);
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: it is not working. What can it be? The preferenceActivity is not working

Comment: I copied that code from my own PreferenceActivity which uses EXACTLY that code (you are initialising username BEFORE creating the PreferenceActivity - yes??)

If you run your app on the Emulator (or a rooted phone), you can see the preference XML files using the DDMS File Browser and check they're being created and updated correctly.

They're named as data\data\preferences\YOURPACKAGENAME\preferencesname.xml

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late, but you can also check out [Swarm's Cloud Data](http://swarmconnect.com/cloud_data), which provides a per-user SharedPreferences system, stored in the cloud (so if the user switches devices, their preferences persist on the new device).